# Assigning an ACF field as variable inside an array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get the int value of a variable to an array but it doesn't work. The code below first prints the myvariable then do what it intends to do without getting the category.

I'm using ACF. my_acf_field is a field that holds a category id as its value.

```
<?php 
    $myvariable = the_field('my_acf_field');
    $args=array(
    'cat'           => $myvariable,
    'orderby'      => 'rand',
    'numberposts'    => 6,
);
    $posts = get_posts( $args ); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

    <div class="related-posts">
        <p>Some stuff</p>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that I need to use get_field('my_acf_field') instead of the_field('my_acf_field').

```
<?php 
    $myvariable = get_field('my_acf_field');
    $args=array(
    'cat'           => $myvariable,
    'orderby'      => 'rand',
    'numberposts'    => 6,
);
    $posts = get_posts( $args ); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

    <div class="related-posts">
        <p>Some stuff</p>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```